# Simulating CancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested when unit testing

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asynchronous, rhino-mocks

I would like to test a task that is supposed to run continuously until killed. Suppose the following method is being tested:

```cs
public class Worker
{
  public async Task Run(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
  {
    while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
      try
      {
        // do something like claim a resource
      }
      catch (Exception e)
      {
        // catch exceptions and print to the log
      }
      finally
      {
        // release the resource
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And a test case

```cs
[TestCase]
public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task Run_ShallAlwaysReleaseResources()
{
  // Act
  await domainStateSerializationWorker.Run(new CancellationToken());  

  // Assert
  // assert that resource release has been called
}
```

The problem is that the task never terminates, because cancellation is never requested. Ultimately I would like to create a `CancellationToken` stub like `MockRepository.GenerateStub<CancellationToken>()` and tell it on which call to `IsCancellationRequested` return `true`, but `CancellationToken` is not a reference type so it is not possible.

So the question is how to make a test where `Run` executes for `n` iterations and then terminates? Is it possible without refactoring `Run`?

Comment: something like`var tokenSource = new  CancellationTokenSource(); Task.Run(async () => await Task.Delay(1000); tokenSource.Cancel()); await domainStateSerializationWorker.Run(tokenSource.Token);` will cancel after 1s

Comment: so termination after n iteration is is not possible but after some defined time it is

Comment: @Selvin With this approach test result would be nondeterministic. I want `Run` to run for `x`iterations, not `x` seconds

Comment: you can mock some object where you are storaing result of work and cancel from it (if in where `do something like claim a resource` you have something like `observer.SendResult(...);` then you can try to mock `observer.SendResult` and cancel token after n calls) .... **without more code/context question is not answerable**

Comment: You might be able to get there with some weird Reflection code, but refactoring `Run` - even if you initially didn't want to do it - is probably the most (cost) effective way to get what you want.

Comment: @SergiiGryshkevych This depends on what is running within Run. Is there some injected dependency that can be mocked and monitored to count how many times some member has been invoked?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This depends on what is running within `Run`. If there is some injected dependency

For example

```
public interface IDependency {
    Task DoSomething();
}

public class Worker {
    private readonly IDependency dependency;

    public Worker(IDependency dependency) {
        this.dependency = dependency;
    }

    public async Task Run(CancellationToken cancellationToken) {
        while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested) {
            try {
                // do something like claim a resource
                await dependency.DoSomething();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // catch exceptions and print to the log
            } finally {
                // release the resource
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then that can be mocked and monitored to count how many times some member has been invoked.

```
[TestClass]
public class WorkerTests {
    [TestMethod]
    public async Task Sohuld_Cancel_Run() {
        //Arrange
        int expectedCount = 5;
        int count = 0;
        CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        var mock = new Mock<IDependency>();
        mock.Setup(_ => _.DoSomething())
            .Callback(() => {
                count++;
                if (count == expectedCount)
                    cts.Cancel();
            })
            .Returns(() => Task.FromResult<object>(null));

        var worker = new Worker(mock.Object);

        //Act
        await worker.Run(cts.Token);

        //Assert
        mock.Verify(_ => _.DoSomething(), Times.Exactly(expectedCount));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

The best you can do without changing your code is cancelling after a specific amount of time. The [`CancellationTokenSource.CancelAfter()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtokensource.cancelafter?view=netframework-4.8) method makes this easy:

```cs
[TestCase]
public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task Run_ShallAlwaysReleaseResources()
{

  // Signal cancellation after 5 seconds
  var cts = new TestCancellationTokenSource();
  cts.CancelAfter(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));

  // Act
  await domainStateSerializationWorker.Run(cts.Token);  

  // Assert
  // assert that resource release has been called
}
```

The way your code is written (checking `IsCancellationRequested` only once per iteration) means that the cancellation will happen after *some* number of complete iterations. It just won't be the same number each time.

If you want to cancel after a specific number of iterations, then your only option is to modify your code to keep track of how many iterations have happened.

I thought I might be able to create a new class that inherits from `CancellationTokenSource` to keep track of how many times `IsCancellationRequested` has been tested, but it's just not possible to do.

Comment: *wait 6 just to be safe* don't you worry.... It will be never called... Also IsCancellationRequested is a property of CancellationToken struct not CancellationTokenSource class

Comment: @Selvin Yeah I guess `Run` won't return until the cancellation happens. My bad. I fixed that. But also, `IsCancellationRequested` is a proptery of both, and `CancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested` just [returns the value from `CancellationTokenSource.IsCancellationRequested`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/CancellationToken.cs,86).